# Routing Error: No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out" - Devise 4.1

Tags: ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4.2

So I've been creating my webapp and ran into an issue with Devise. Here are my different files.

devise.rb file

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
config.sign_out_via = :get if Rails.env.test?
```

index.html.erb file

```
<li>
   <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
</li>
```

routes.rb file

```
devise_for :users do
  get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end
```

The issue is that if I press "Logout" on my webapp, I immediately get:

```
No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
```

When I run rake routes | grep destroy_user, this is the response.

```
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
```

Not sure what's wrong. How do I fix this? I'm using rails 4.2.1 / devise 4.1.1. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting errors when requesting with `method: :delete` and you see `Matches [GET]` then that's usually a problem loading the UJS file.

Make sure `application.js` is properly packaged and is loading jQuery and the rest of the Rails JavaScript it needs to function properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I fixed the issue by replacing this in `application.js` :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

With:

```
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

It was that simple :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - for me it was that I had not loaded jquery_ujs at all. (I had some problems with js in the latest version of bootstrap, decided to get all I needed from a CDN, commented out my application.js, which had the reference to jquery_ujs in it.